# Lilypond: define MIDI output file name

Tags: midi, lilypond

I am trying to make Lilypond create a MIDI output file whose name corresponds song title, but I didn't succeed so far. Maybe someone can help?

From the Lilypond notation reference (https://lilypond.org/doc/v2.20/Documentation/notation/creating-output-file-metadata):

> For each type of output file, only the \header definitions of blocks that define separate files of that type, and blocks higher in the block hierarchy, will be consulted. Therefore, [...] for MIDI files, all headers above or at the \score level are used.

Here is my code:

```
\music = { \relative c'4 d e f}

\bookpart {
  \header {
    title = "my Title"
  }
  \score {
    \music
    \midi { }
  }
}
```

I expected to get a midi file named `my Title.midi`, but instead, I get a file whose name is the name of the lilypond file (so if `myLilypondFile.ly`, then `myLilypondFile.midi`).

From the same source:

> The title variable sets also the sequence name for MIDI. The midititle variable can be used to set the sequence name independently of the value used for typeset output.

So I tried adding `midititle` to my existing header:

```
\header {
    title = "my Title"
    midititle = "my midi Title"
}
```

but it did not change anything. It seems the `midititle` variable isn't even known (I use Frescobaldi and it does not syntax highlight that variable).

My lilypond file is version 2.20.0 and I have also installed GNU lilypond 2.20.0.

Comment: May I ask how that would help you? For me, getting `myLilypondFile.midi` out of `myLilypondFile.ly` sounds very reasonable (apart from `myLilypondFile` being a very unhelpful file name). I don't even think Lilypond can put things into arbitrarily named files. Btw. "sequence name" is a name stored within the MIDI. Some MIDI players, like timidity, will show it while playing, some (most?) will not.

Comment: Don't put too much stock into whether Frescobaldi recognizes things like "midititle".  The syntax highlighting sometimes lags behind the latest version, and somethings are just missing.

Comment: @Ramillies My file contains several songs and I want to create midi files for each of them in order to check if I wrote the scores correctly. Standard behaviour is the creation of `myLilypondFile.midi`, `myLilypondFile-1.midi`, `myLilypondFile-2.midi` and so on. But with this, it is hard to find the right file for a certain song.

Comment: @Kjara: Then I would tell you to use `\bookOutputSuffix` (which would change the `-1`, `-2` etc. to something else -- one use could be `mySong-soprano.midi`, `mySong-alto.midi` etc.), but the answer below is more universal.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're on the right track for sheet music title and midi file title, but you should use `\bookOutputName` to control the resulting filename:

```
\header {
  title = "File title"
  midititle = "midi title"
}
music = \relative c' {
  c1
}
\book {
  \bookOutputName "pdf_file_only"
  \score {
    \new Staff \music
  \layout {}
  }
}
\book {
  \bookOutputName "midi_file_only"
  \score {
    \new Staff \music
  \midi {}
  }
}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Wow, I knew about `\bookOutputSuffix` but I didn't know (or think) this would exist...